# PHP Get all users data and check lastonline for each

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get each users lastonline time and then check to see if the time now minus their last online time is smaller than 600 seconds after their last login.

I have made a little peice of code which works but not what I want it to do.
I want it to get each users information. For some reason, this code updates every users info depending on 1 user im pretty sure. When I change the smaller than sign in my code to a bigger than sign, they all change with it even-though ***my*** users last online time is 1 minute ago.

My code :

```
<?php
    $user_grab = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users");
    while($users_ = mysqli_fetch_array($user_grab)) {

        foreach($users as $user) {
            $last_online = $users_['lastonline'];

            if(time() - $last_online < user_session_timeout()) {
                echo '
                     <div class="chat-list-item -available" style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);">
                        <img class="chat-list-avatar" src="'.$users_['profile_picture'].'"/><i class="fa fa-circle chat-list-status"> </i>
                        <div class="chat-list-user">'.$users_['username'].'</div>
                        <div class="chat-list-excerpt">Online</div>
                     </div>
                ';
            } else {
                echo '
                     <div class="chat-list-item -offline" style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1); padding: 5px;">
                        <img class="chat-list-avatar" src="'.$users_['profile_picture'].'"/><i class="fa fa-circle chat-list-status"> </i>
                        <div class="chat-list-user">'.$users_['username'].'</div>
                        <div class="chat-list-excerpt">Offline</div>
                     </div>
                ';
            }   
        }
    }
?>
```

My user_session_timeout just reads the time a user hasn't changed page until the users should be redirected

Code for `user_session_timeout():`

```
function user_session_timeout() {
global $con;
    $grab_user_timeout_sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT user_session_timeout FROM sitesettings");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($grab_user_timeout_sql);
    return $row['user_session_timeout'];
}
```

Picture of my users all offline display

[image]

Proof that each users last online time is different

[image]

Comment: `user_session_timeout()` at least sounds like it has something to do with the current user. What does it do?

Comment: @colburton I just updated my question. It just reads 600 seconds as an integer from my database.

Comment: Your `foreach` loop never uses `$user` for anything. Why are you looping there?

Comment: @Barmar Yes I'm not too sure. I took it out and still the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$users_["lastonline"]` is a string containing a date and time. You need to parse it to a numeric timestamp so you can subtract it from `time()`.

```
$last_online = strtotime($users_['lastonline']);
```